# behaviour of decode in oracle when search is null

Tags: sql, oracle

I was reading the [Oracle `decode()` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions040.htm). As far as I know, when calling `decode(expr, search1, value1, search2, value2...)` Oracle casts `expr`, `search2` and `search3`  to the type of `search1` and compare them.

So if `search1` is `NULL` then what will `search2`, `search3`, etc. be cast to?

**Example**:

```
create table sc(a date, b varchar2(256));

insert into sc values(
  to_date('2010-01-01 11:22:33', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'),
  '2010-01-01 11:22:33'
);

select decode(
         to_date('2010-01-01 11:22:33', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'),
         null,
         1,
         b,
         123,
         a,
         456
       )
from   sc;
```

Why is the result 456 rather than 123?

Comment: because the first value is a date, the decode will match it with "a" which is a date.  You could try to rewrite this as a "case when ... then ... when .. then .. end)" to understand better what decode tries to do.  Mostly decode isn't used this way, but more like this : "decode(myint,1,'one',2,'two')"

Comment: thanks for your reply. so kind of you. when we call decode(1, null, 22,  '1', 33, 1, 44) we will get 33 not 44.

Comment: i am sorry, but are you sure ??? SELECT DECODE( 1, NULL, 1, 33, '1', 44 ) FROM DUAL outputs 44 not 33

Comment: Sorry, typo in the above - missed a value `SELECT DECODE( 1, NULL, 22, 1, 33, '1', 44 ) FROM DUAL;` outputs  33.

Comment: Normally, nothing equals NULL, even NULL. Decode is an exception, in that NULL can equal NULL. Type is not relevant to this, as NULL is not its own type as it is in some languages -- e.g. Ruby -- and a NULL date is still a date

Comment: Perhaps it's less of a problem for number values. But using decode to translate a date value should be against values of the same type.  As Mottor's answer demonstrates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: 
When the first value to compare with is null or char, all values will be converted to varchar2 and compared as strings. So compare always equal types and do not use null as first compare value if you do not compare strings:

```
select decode(
         to_date('2010-01-01 11:22:33', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'),
         to_date('2010-01-01 11:22:31', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'),
         0,
         null,
         1,
         to_char(to_date('2010-01-01 11:22:33', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')),
         2,
         to_date(b, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'),
         123,
         a,
         456
       )
from   sc;
```

If the first compare value is NULL, the date will be converted to string with the default date representation (which can be different from this in b) and compared with b. if you want to see the default, use this:

```
select to_char(to_date('2010-01-01 11:22:33', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')),b from sc
```

If we read the Oracle Documentation:

> If the first result has the datatype CHAR or if the first result is
>   null, then Oracle converts the return value to the datatype VARCHAR2.

The same happens with values. First value is null, then everything is converted to string.. You can see it here.

```
SELECT DECODE (1, NULL, 1,  '01', 2,  '1 ', 3,  '1', 4,  1, 5) FROM DUAL;
```

Now change the null with a number

```
SELECT DECODE (1, 5, 1,  '01', 2,  '1 ', 3,  '1', 4,  1, 5) FROM DUAL;
```

What will give this:

```
SELECT DECODE (TO_DATE ('2010-01-01 11:22:33', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'),  
               NULL, 1,  
               TO_DATE ('2010-01-01 15:22:32', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 2,  
               '3') 
FROM DUAL
```

Answer (score 1):

To give you a better understanding

```
SELECT DECODE( 1, NULL, 1, 33, '1', 44 ) FROM DUAL;
```

will give you 44 because, It cannot find 1 in the find field and goes for the default.

```
( 1,               -> Search expression
NULL, 1,           -> Find and replace
33, 1,             -> Find and replace
 44 )              -> default

44
```

Also

```
SELECT DECODE( 1, NULL, 22, 1, 33, '1', 44 ) FROM DUAL;
```

will give you 33 because, It finds 1 in the find field and goes for the replace value (33).

```
( 1,               -> Search expression
NULL, 22,          -> Find and replace
1, 33,             -> Find and replace
1, 44 )            -> Find and replace and no default

33
```

Also

```
SELECT DECODE( 1, NULL, 22, 1, 33, '1', 44 ) FROM DUAL;
```

will give you NULL because, It cannot find 1 in the find field and goes for the default which doesn't exist.

```
( 1,               -> Search expression
NULL, 22,          -> Find and replace
2, 33,             -> Find and replace
2, 44 )            -> Find and replace and no default

(null)
```

Comment: thx. yeah. this is easy to understand. i knew it. my question is when search1 is null, what cast type will be used ? how to decide it ? in another word, how to decide equals or not when the two operands are of different datatypes ? thx